# Bloqueio IP ServerSocket?

Tags: delphi, socket

Desenvolvi um sistema de sockets em Delphi. É possível bloquear um IP para não se conectar no meu server?

*Obs:* Foi usado os componentes: **SERVERSOCKET** e **CLIENTSOCKET**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que isso seja possível.

Para bloquear uma lista de endereços(seja num `Memo` ou numa `StringList`) você pode usar uma função como essa:

```
{ Verifica se uma lista contem determinada string(IP bloqueado) }
function IpIsBlocked(List: TStrings; const IPBlocked: string): Boolean;
Var
I: Integer;
begin
Result := False;
for i := 0 to List.Count -1 do
if List.Strings[I] = IPBlocked then
Result := True;
end;
```

Agora basta utilizar a função *IpIsBlocked* no evento [`OnClientConnect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TServerSocket.OnClientConnect) do *ServerSocket*.

Exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
if IpIsBlocked(Memo1.Lines, 'XXX.XYX.XXX') then begin
ShowMessage(Format('O ip %s está bloqueado!', [socket.RemoteAddress]));
Socket.Close;
end;
end;
```

Bom, basicamente é isto.

Comment: Obrigado Amigos!

Comment: Amigo deu erro nessa linha: if Form6.ListBox1.Strings[I] = IPBlocked then na opção STRINGS.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível. Você pode interceptar a conexão do cliente no evento ClientConnect do ServerSocket

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  if not ValidaAcesso(Socket.RemoteAddress, Socket.RemotePort) then
    raise EConnException.Create('Endereço não autorizado!')
end;
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Essa função VALIDA ACESSO seria mais ou menos como ? Eu poderia por exemplo ter um MEMO com vários ips dentro e ele consultar dentro desse MEMO se existe o IP bloqueado lá ?

Comment: Opa! Deixa eu dar uma sapeada! @user7605 seria por ai sim. É um método que você vai especificar conforme sua necessidade. Está sendo passado como parâmetro o endereço IP e a Porta, então você escreve esse método `ValidaAcesso` para verificar essa lista de IP´s e/ou outras verificações que precisar.

Comment: Vou montar esta função então, obrigado amigos pela ajuda!

Comment: Tiago ou user7605, criei algo do tipo, mais não funcionou, o que eu fiz de errado ? function ValidaAcesso(S: string): string;
begin
s := Form6.Memo1.Text;
end;

Comment: Já deu certo aqui amigos, muito obrigado!

Comment: @user7605 Já que deu certo, basta marcas a resposta como correta, para que a pergunta saia da fila das sem resposta.